# Flutter doctor not recognized iPhone whereas Xcode does

Tags: ios, flutter

I setup Flutter workflow on my Mac (macOS 10.14.6) and I can create a project, use Xcode/Android/VsCode and run my project on the simulators.
But, I can't run my project on my own iOS device (Iphone 7).

Each time I ran the command line `flutter doctor` i've got the message `No devices available`, I precise that I've done all installation instructions from Flutter official documentation.
[flutter - macOS install](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos)

I also precise that my iPhone is running iOS 13.
Any ideas?

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G95, locale en-FR)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.2 at /Users/louisbertin/flutter
    • Framework revision 2d2a1ffec9 (2 weeks ago), 2019-09-06 18:39:49 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/louisbertin/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.0, Build version 11A420a
    • CocoaPods version 1.7.5

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 39.0.3
    • Dart plugin version 191.8423
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[✓] VS Code (version 1.38.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.4.1

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Hi @MiguelRuivo!
Desperately.. I didn't find any solution for this problem..
Maybe I should try with the latest version of Flutter

Comment: actually after re-installing Flutter completely, it starting to work. I believe that I had some missing files (can't really remember now which) that somehow might have been deleted.

Comment: I will reinstall Flutter in the next few days, i will come back here to tell you if it works.

Comment: Finally everything works when I have reinstalled flutter. But, the memory consumption is huge on VsCode so I switch to Android Studio.
The memory consumption is better on it.. but if you have any idea to improve it, I might be interested!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running this commands fixed it for me.

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Mine occurred after I updated my Xcode. I hope you will find it useful as well.